# what does が in paragraph mean

Tags: grammar

> 家にお友だちが来たとき、案の定戦いごっこが始まりました。相手をやっつけるフリのところで、口々に「死ね！」「バカ野郎！」の**声**が。その場にいたママたちは真っ青になって「そんなこと言っちゃダメ、ほかの遊びをしなさい！」と、おもちゃを出すとすぐそちらに移ったのですが、言葉を覚え始めてそんなに経っていない子に「ダメ！」と言ったところで、あるいは説明したところで、分かるのだろうかと…。

I looked up a dictionary,the only plausible explanation I can find  is

> （多く体言や体言の下にののしる意の接尾語「め」を伴ったものに付いて）ののしりの感情を強める。「このあほうめが」「あいつめが」

but the が in my paragraph doesn't have め before it,so I not sure wether it is used in this way.

Comment: Does the sentence actually end there?

Comment: https://www.kobe-np.co.jp/rentoku/omoshiro/202211/0015808396.shtml     家にお友だちが来たとき、案の定戦いごっこが始まりました。相手をやっつけるフリのところで、口々に「死ね！」「バカ野郎！」の声が。その場にいたママたちは真っ青になって「そんなこと言っちゃダメ、ほかの遊びをしなさい！」と、おもちゃを出すとすぐそちらに移ったのですが、言葉を覚え始めてそんなに経っていない子に「ダメ！」と言ったところで、あるいは説明したところで、分かるのだろうかと…。

Answer (score 1):

Let's examine the part where the が is concerned:

> 口々に「死ね！」「バカ野郎！」の声が

Here, it's actually short for

> 口々に「死ね！」「バカ野郎！」の声が**した**。
> The mouths voices/said "die!" "moron!"

In Japanese, unlike English, nouns like 声 and 匂い and 気 could use する to mean "there is this (noun) going on" Example:

> 冬の風の匂いがする There is the smell of wintry winds
> 外で大きな声がした There was a loud voice outside

In your example sentence, it's just that the する is omitted since it doesn't create any ambiguity for anyone well-versed in Japanese — once they see 声が they know automatically it's 声がする.

Such omissions are actually quite common in Japanese, and the words omitted are not just する, whenever in a context the verb can be inferred from context, it's possible to omit the verb and leave only the particles.

> 全てを俺に！ Give me everything!
> 全てを俺に**渡せ**！　全てを俺に**くれ**！ 全てを俺に**与えろ**！

Which one? Well it doesn't matter since 全てを俺に is already complete in meaning the verb is omitted, so it could be any of these verbs, but they all mean pretty much the same thing, which is "Give/hand me everything!" If the author sees the need to clarify to specify the action, he would've done so.

Comment: so in the same logic 思う  is omitted after と(the last one)  in "あるいは説明したところで、分かるのだろうかと…" ?

Comment: Yep. There is 100% a verb omitted, and from context I'd say here the omitted is indeed 思う. It all depends on context though, and the next time there's a hanging と the verb could be 言う, 答える, or anything. Ex: `母は「ご飯食べたの」と聞いた時、僕は「もう食べちゃったんだよ」と。` Here, the verb is 答えた that I'm omitting.